# subtracting month AND days with dateadd()

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Trying to get minus 1 month and 6 days from todays date GETDATE()??

```
SELECT (DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE()) + (DATEADD(d,-6,GETDATE())))
```

This is returning : 2132-11-02 01:10:33.500

Comment: Try putting the second `DATEADD` around the first. So you add the days to the result of the first call. What you're doing now is summing two dates, which doesn't make sense really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -6, DATEADD(mm,-1, GETDATE()))
```